# how to best express ’always' in Chinese

Tags: grammar

I struggle to differentiate 从来都，一直，总，and总是 since according to their definitions they all mean 'always'.Can they all fill this:她（）在图书馆学习。and mean ,she always studies in the library?

Comment: Don't forget 老 and 老是. Also 一向. And 向来.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

现代汉语虚词词典 (张斌)

Page 112, 从来:

> 表示从过去到现在情形一直如此，没有变化。多用于否定句式，有时也可以用于肯定句式，所修饰的必须是动词，形容词的复杂形式或小句。

(从来 is often used in negative sentences; but occasionally in positive sentences. The modified phrase must be a verb, a complex phrase headed by an adjective, or a clause.)

Page 619-620, 一直:

> 1. 从以前到现在，甚至到将来，始终如此。 (This is the same meaning as 从来)
> 2. 在过去的某一段时间内始终如此。 Example: 在边疆，他一直干了五年，始终没有回过家。 (This sense cannot be replaced with 从来)

> 比较“一直”与“从来”：
>
> 1. “一直”可以表示距今较近的时间，如“他这几天一直生病”，不能改用“从来”。 (一直 can be used for a period close to present.)
> 2. “从来”多用于否定句，“一直”常用于肯定句。 (从来 is often used in negative sentences; 一直 is often used in positive sentences.)
> 3. “一直”可以表示从过去到将来的情况，如“你必须一直等到明年才能离职”，不能改用“从来”。 (一直 can be used when the period extends to the future, 从来 cannot be used in this situation.)

Page 762-764, 总:

> 1. 表示一种对事实的确认，强调动作、行为、性质、状态从过去到现在一直如此，很少例外。 (Almost the same as 一直.)
> 2. 与“也”连用，有强调的意味，相当于“一直”，后面多接动词，只限于否定句。 (总也 can be used as an emphasized version of 一直, it is usually followed by a verb, and can only be used in negative sentences.)
> 3. 用在“X总是X”的格式中，表示对作为理由的事实的认定，含申辩口气。 Example: 黑的总是黑的，不能变成白的。 (总是 can be used in phrases of the format "X is X".)

Page 765, 总是:

> 1. 表示动作、行为、性质、状态从过去到现在一直如此，很少例外。有强调的意味。 (An emphasized version of 总.)
> 2. 表示事情和情况必然会如此，相当于“终归”，常用于条件句中。有强调的意思。 Example: 不管条件好坏，他总是提前完成工作任务。 (总是 can be used to mean "always, no matter what".)

老(是) is very similar to 总(是), the slight difference being 老(是) is more colloquial and has some connotation of being annoyed by the situation.

一向 is also close to 一直, but there are differences which I cite below.

Page 616, 一向:

> 比较“一向”与“一直”.
>
> 1. “一向”值过去到说话这一段时间，不再指将来。“一直”可以指将来。如：“这条高架路是去年年初开工的，预计一直要到明年年底才能完工。” (一向 only entails the period from past to current, not future.)
> 2. “一向”指的是从过去到现在，“一直”可以表示某一段时间是如此。如：“紧张的舌战一直延续了四个小时。”这里的“一直”即无起点，又无终点，只说明了时段。 (一直 can be used for a period ended in the past, 一向 can only be used for a period extending up to current time.)
> 3. “一向”只用来表示时间，“一直”除了表示时间之外，还可以用来说明空间。如“地铁一直延伸到莘庄”。

一向 and 向来 are very similar and largely interchangeable. However there is one special use of 向来 that cannot be replaced with 一向.

> “向来”可以用在主语前，如“向来，我总不相信国粹家道德家之类的痛哭流涕是真心”。

(向来 can be placed at the front of a sentence, this use cannot be replaced by 一直, 一向, 总, 从来, etc.)

Regarding your question: 她____在图书馆学习, here 一直, 一向, 总, 总是, 一向, 向来 are all acceptable. I would not use 从来 because it prefers negative sentences, unless this sentence is used to imply some kind of negation, as in 她从来都是在图书馆学习，不会在家里学习。